# Avoid the # in URL in angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular app which uses angular-ui-router for routing.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
      });
  });
```

The code above produces the url

```
localhost:3000/#/home
```

when I want it to be

```
localhost:3000/home
```

I tried omitting the `url` property which results in just `localhost:3000`.

Is there any way I can get the url to be `localhost:3000/home`?
And how do I provide each state with it's own title?

Answer (score 1):

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true):